# $L$ is algebraic curve. Why has $L$ finitely many singularities?($x,y\in \mathbb{R}$)

Tags: calculus, algebraic-curves, curves, implicit-function-theorem

Let

${L_1} = \left\{ {x + iy:x,y \in \mathbb{R},{f_1}(x,y) = (\sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} )p{{(x,y)}^{}} + q{{(x,y)}^{}} = 0} \right\} \subseteq {L_2} = \left\{ {x + iy:x,y \in \mathbb{R},{f_2}(x,y) = ({x^2} + {y^2})p{{(x,y)}^2} - q{{(x,y)}^2} = 0} \right\}$

and $p,q$ are two polynomials.Assume that $p$ and $q$ are coprime ($L_2$ is algeraic curve.)

Why has $L_1$ finitely many singularities?(How can we prove, by Bezout's theorem )

Comment: $L$ is not an algebraic curve  because of the square root used in its definition.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg -  You are right. I edited this post. Please more guide.

Answer (score 2):

The singular points of the curve with equation $f=0$ are the solutions of the system of equations $$f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0.$$ In other words, the set of solutions is the intersection of the three curves 
\begin{align}
&f=0, && \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0, && \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0.
\end{align}

Can you use Bézout's theorem to bound the number of points in this intersection?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand that why,  have not $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$  a common factor?

Comment: What common factor do they have?

Comment: -Is it true that: by Bézout's theorem,if  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ have not a common factor then finitly the number of points in this intersection.-----Bézout's theorem for curves states that, in general, two algebraic curves of degrees $m$ and $n$ intersect in m·n points and cannot meet in more than $m·n$ points unless they have a component in common (i.e., the equations defining them have a common factor)

Comment: Yes,  I know. What I am proposing, then, is that you show that you *can* apply that theorem in this situation and, therefore, inviting you to check the hypothesis!

Comment: You are right. I edited this post. Please more guide.

Comment: But can you or can you not apply the theorem? Have you tried checking if $f$ and $\partial f/\partial x$ have a common factor?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not apply the theorem.I shad be grateful, if you guide me.(Please)

Comment: I think it is better if you actually try. To warm up, consider a polynomial $f\in\mathbb R[x]$. Can $f$ and its derivative $f'$ share a non-trivial factor?

Comment: In this case I solved this question. What about $f\in\mathbb R[x,y]$?

Comment: Well, *how* did you solve it?

Comment: (($f$ and $f'$ have a nontrivial common factor iff $f$ has a nontrivial square factor.))

Let $p$ be an *irreducible* common factor of $f$ and $f'$. Then $f=pg$ and $f'=ph$ and so $ph=f'=pg'+p'g$. This implies that $p$ divides $p'g$. Since $p$ cannot divide $p'$ because of degrees, $p$ must divide $g$ and so $p^2$ divides $f$.

If $f=g^2h$ then $f'=2gg'h+g^2h'=g(2g'h+gh')$ and $g$ is a common factor of $f$ and $f'$.

Comment: Notice that you are not done. It is easier to let P be a irreducible common factor of f and f' and k be the maximal integer such that $p^k$ divides f. Then proceed more or less as you did.

Comment: Once you have really done that case, do **exactly** the same thing with a polynomial in the variables and one of its derivatives.